# POST 405 (Method not allowed) when trying to post AJAX request - Laravel 5.5

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.5

I am trying to issue a simple AJAX request to populate a menu in Laravel, however, I am having a lot of trouble with getting it to work properly.

I am not sure what the issue is, and after a couple hours of searching, I cannot find anything that can help.

**Here is my AJAX request:**

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url  : url,
        data : formData,
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        } 
    });
```

My route to the AJAX callback:

```
Route::post('/newCustomer','CustomerController@newCustomer');
```

When sending the AJAX request, it returns with the fail message in the error parameters, and in the console, it tells me:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

which gives the full URL:POST http://localhost:8000/ 405 (Method Not Allowed) but that does not solve the issue either.

[ERROR IMAGE](https://filehost.net/78b575bc82be1a6d)

Comment: You should be POSTing to `/newCustomer`, not `/`

Comment: Are you doing a cross-origin request? If so you need to configure your backend to support cross origin requests, as well as, depending on the browser, enable additional verbs that get sent BEFORE it sends the POST request. If the initial request fails it, typically returns a 405 Method not allowed response. If my memory serves me right you need to enable the OPTIONS verb. Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems like a web server misconfiguration. Do other POST requests work? Like the built-in ones, login etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass csrf_token. Add this line in `<head>`

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

then in ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url  : url,
    data : formData,
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}, //Add this <-----
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    } 
});
```

Comment: I faced the same issue yesterday. Adding <meta> tag in <head> then in my ajax request adding 'headers' solved the problem.

Comment: The guy is posting to `/`, not to `/newCustomer` and his problem isn't related to CSRF token, it's related to sending data to wrong URL.

Comment: @rahulsingh could you post what is in your variable url?

Comment: Please find my project with this link : [link]  https://filehost.net/9e68b6ac0873d77e 
[link]

Comment: it would be better if you give us the url. console.log(url). then from your console give us the output

Comment: If you **read** the question he posted, he's sending data to `POST http://localhost:8000/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)`. He'll probably have CSRF issue once he figures out what a path is, and most likely CORS issue.

Comment: I noticed that later too. Now i just wanna point him out the error he is having.

Answer (score 0):

Did you write something like this inside the form submission handler?

`$('#some_name').on('action', function (e) {`

```
    e.preventDefault(); //<---if yes then comment this line of code.

}
```

N.B: I had the same problem. Just commenting out this line solved the problem.
Happy coding :)